# Leaflet: Grouped layers and accordion menu - How to implement?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, leaflet, mapbox

I have a single geojson featurecollection. Each feature has a Subcategory property and a main Category property (ex. "Subcategory": "Brown regional airport", "Category": "Aviation")

I was able to group the subcategories into a main category by using the [Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol](https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol) Leaflet plugin.

Here's a live example: [**[demo link](http://ogmda.com/sandbox/map.html)**]

The problem is that in my real case scenario, I have a lot of categories and subcategories and this is way too many layers to show at once in the layer control. Thus, I need some sort of accordion/drop down menu to display the subcategories for only one category at a time like shown in the below graphic:

Does anyone have any advice on a way to approach my issue? Something like this would be ideal:

[image]

Would I be injecting an accordion template into the DOM using Javascript?  Newbie here, so looking for tips and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Open feature request for collapsing groups: https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin does not provide a way to alter the template of the created html.

So i have resorted to altering the DOM dynamically through jQuery, and using CSS for the tricks.

So adding

```
$('.leaflet-control-layers-group-label').each(function(index){
    var self = $(this),
        trigger = $('<label>', {
        html: '▼',
        class:'trigger',
        for: 'dropdown-trigger-' + index
      }).insertBefore(self),
      radio = $('<input>', {
        type : 'radio',
        class: 'trigger-radio',
        name : 'dropdown-control',
        id: 'dropdown-trigger-' + index
      }).insertBefore(trigger);
});
```

after adding the layer will add a label/radio combo for each group which will control (through the following CSS) the display/hide of the subcategories.

```
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-group-label{
  padding-left:20px;
  display:block
}
.leaflet-control-layers label{
  padding-left:40px;
  padding-right:10px;
  display:none;
}
.leaflet-control-layers label.trigger{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.leaflet-control-layers .trigger-radio{display:none;}
.leaflet-control-layers .trigger-radio:checked ~ label{display:block;}
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/La77L8L9/2/

---

***note***. it currently uses hidden radio buttons to open/close the subcategories (*so only only one can be open at a time and it cannot close until another is selected*). Changing the `type : 'radio',` line to `type : 'checkbox',` will allow for each category to be opened/closed on its own.

Comment: This worked great! Looks like it is compatible in all major browsers. Do you know how I could modify the code so I can use Font Awesome icons in place of the triangles? Thanks!

Comment: You could alter the `html: '▼'` line and change the arrow down to the html you want.

Comment: @redshift, sorry.. If you are using the latest jsfiddle then I am setting the icons from css. You need to set the font-family to fontawesome and use the appropriate char. You could of course change the script a bit to allow for any custom html.. If you have something in particular you are trying to add let me know. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/La77L8L9/3/

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrapping those labels inside a `ul` that is by default with `display: none`. Then you can write some javascript and make that `ul` visible based user's selection.

If you provide a codepen/jsfiddle for me I'd be more than happy to help.

Meanwhile you can use my image to see what I mean.

[image]
[image]

And the JS will be similar with (this is very rudimental):

```
if ($('.leaflet-control-layers-group-selector').is(":checked")) {
  // Match the closest ul and call #show
} else {
  // Match the closest ul and call #hide
}
```

Changing then the CSS with arrows and everything will be fairly easy.

Comment: Brilliant idea! I Just made a jsfiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/y6s8f91v/  . I had to paste the plugin code in the editor .

Comment: The backup idea I had didn't work, so if you still have your idea, i'd love to see it. Thanks!